# Why does openshift ingress not allow router annotations?

Tags: annotations, openshift, haproxy-ingress

Small question for you.

I have just setup a dev openshift cluster in the cloud and I am trying to create an ingress yaml to define router settings. I basically just want to stop the default redirect policy from forwarding http request to https.... Is there a way to set the "**insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy**" through ingress?  I see there is one for nginx, but unfortunately, I am using the default haproxy setup with openshift...

```
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
labels:
  app.kubernetes.io/name: app-web
spec:
  host: apptest.dev
  path: /
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: tcp-8080
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

Basically in openshift, if I define a a ingress route, openshift will automatically create the route with the ingress shortname. The only way I can think of doing this is with a patch, but I am looking for a better way. So, I thought I would ask...

Ta,

X

Comment: Why not creating a route directly with the exact spec you need instead of an ingress?

Comment: Hi, titou10, It is because I want a ingress host short name rather than a long hashed one...

Comment: You can set whatever hostname you want in a Route resource.